Sites shutting down, what is our position?
I'd like everyone of you to be aware of the fact that some SE sites are being shut down.
What is our position? Today, April 26th 2012 our stats are the following (you can see the stats here):

It's still not enough. We need to seriously do something, and take a minute to consider this issue. I would like to avoid our site ending in that list of sites that are going to be shut down.
The main thing you can do is share. It doesn't matter if you don't have people in your friends list that are not studying Chinese. Share questions, share the site on any place it can gain (even occasional) visibility. We have 90 avid users. If everyone of you brings only one person each, there will be another 90 and so on. 

Things we can do (also taking inspiration from this topic):

Put the link on your SE profile (across all networks), in your signature in other forums, etc
Mention the site in discussions with friends, on forums, etc
Share questions using the appropriate button on social network sites or the site link.

...Any other suggestions? Feel free to add them to this list yourself.

How sad! I don't want this site to be shut down.
The stats seems to indicate that this site lacks questions, not answers. It has too few questions, but almost all questions receive plenty of good answers. 
That matches my personal experience: I just found this site recently. During the first few visits, I tried answering every question I could. A few days later I came back, and found almost no new question. If there is no new question, there won't be many new answers. So basically I had nothing to do. As a result, I had to reduce my frequency of visiting this site.
I propose people ask more questions. Asking questions should be easier than answering them, shouldn't it? If you are a student of Chinese, you are sure to come across many  questions everyday! :)

Thanks for the answer Betty. Yes, we need more questions but the main point is: visits. If you can share this site and tell people about it, more will come and as a consequence, more will post questions... So advertise it anywhere you can! :)

Yes, of course sharing is important. What I mean is, if the current users ask more questions, the site can be more active.

Yes, but that's harder to achieve. I don't always have questions. It's easier, instead, that you bring more people to join this site, so more will be there to ask and answer. Just tell to people in your life, in forums, in sites, in social networks... :P

I think asking question is easier than bring new contributing users. Anyway, these two methods are not mutual-exclusive. One can do both. :)

We will try that too... :P Do you have any suggestions on how?

Did you see my comment?

I'm sure we all have infinite unknown things about Chinese. Whenever we come across Chinese-related things, we can ask why that word is used instead of another, what is the origin of that word, is there any other way to express similar ideas, etc. The possibilities are endless. :)

I just saw this announcement. I have many friends in my social network who study Chinese. I'll try to lure a few of them in. I'm also making a concerted effort to record when I'm not clear in class so that I can ask more questions here.
